# update store on mobx react hook asynchronously

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, mobx, firestorter

I am trying to fetch the data asynchronously from firestore to my local state using react hooks and mobx and got no clue how to update the store after getting data from firestore. I have used https://github.com/IjzerenHein/firestorter/blob/master/docs/API.md#Collection+query

My store

```
    const store = useObservable({
        forms: [],

        async initForms(user_id) {
            console.log(user_id);
            my_forms.query = ref =>
                ref
                    .where('userId', '==', user_id)
                    .limit(20);

            let obj = {};
            const arr = [];
            my_forms.docs.forEach((doc, i) => {
                obj = {
                    key: i + 1,
                    title: doc.data.title,
                    id: doc.id,
                    tags: doc.data.tags,
                    category: doc.data.category,
                    locked: doc.data.locked

                };
                arr.push(obj);
            });
           //i can see records from firestore
           console.log('arr',arr);
           return arr;

        },
    })
```

How i tried to update store

```
useEffect(() => autorun(() => {
        store.forms=store.initForms(user_id);
    }),[]);
```

```
store.forms && (
                        store.forms.length > 0 ? (
                                <FuseAnimateGroup
                                    enter={{
                                        animation: "transition.slideUpBigIn"
                                    }}
                                    className="flex flex-wrap py-24"
                                >
                                    {store.forms.map((f) => {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i fixed it by using classic mobx store and using them as the `context`

These are the steps i did

1. Create the classic mobx store like we used to do in normal react project

```
export class MyFormsStore {
    forms: []

    async initForms(user_id) {
        console.log(user_id);
        my_forms.query = ref =>
            ref
                .where('userId', '==', user_id)
                .limit(20);
        await my_forms.fetch();
        let obj = {};
        const arr = [];
        my_forms.docs.forEach((doc, i) => {
            obj = {
                key: i + 1,
                title: doc.data.title,
                id: doc.id,
                tags: doc.data.tags,
                category: doc.data.category,
                locked: doc.data.locked

            };
            arr.push(obj);
        });
        this.forms = arr;
    }
}

decorate(MyFormsStore, {
    forms: observable
})
```

2. Export it as the `context`

```
export default createContext(new MyFormsStore());
```

3. Play with store as the functional component using `useContext` hook

```
const Forms = observer((props) => {

    const store = useContext(MyFormsStore)
    .
    .
    .
```

4. Fetch the data from firestore using `useEffect` hook

```
    useEffect(() => {
          store.initForms(user_id);
    }, []);
```

5. Check if the store has been initialised or not , it yes render it

```
    {
       store.forms !== undefined && (
           store.forms.length > 0 ? (
        //render
```

**I am still looking how can I memoize expensive functions so that I can avoid calling them on every render using `useMemo`** . Feedbacks will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `useEffect` to update data that is tracked by Mobx.
The simplest way is to use `runInAction` from MobX.
So when your async function is finally resolved, you then use `runInAction` to update the store. And that will eventually trigger the rendering of react components that are using that particular data.

something like this:

```
    async fetchProjects() {
        this.githubProjects = []
        this.state = "pending"
        try {
            const projects = await fetchGithubProjectsSomehow()
            const filteredProjects = somePreprocessing(projects)
            // after await, modifying state again, needs an actions:
            runInAction(() => {
                this.state = "done"
                this.githubProjects = filteredProjects
            })
        } catch (error) {
            runInAction(() => {
                this.state = "error"
            })
        }
    }
```

You can read more in official documentation:
[Writing asynchronous actions](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html)

Comment: Mate, You cant avoid useeffect  when you are using hook . How do I replicate componentDidMount without using useEffect?

Comment: The point is that you use `useEffect` just to fire off mobx action and let mobx handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks mate , please go thru react hooks before answering the questions, I am not discouraging you but it’s nice to move out incorrect and irrelevant answers , I was interested to update  my local state via Mobx  , I can only trigger mobx effects via use effect as I am using hooks .Your answer this.state is not relevant here at all . That’s why I downvoted it